# Как в телеграмм боте вкл и выкл часть кода?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
def sticker_recived(bot, update):
    admins = [admin.user.id for admin in bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=update.message.chat_id)]
    if update.message.from_user.id not in admins:
        bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)
```

вот пример кода. Мне нужно чтобы по команде(например /on) вкл удаление всех стикеров , а по другой команде(например /off) выкл это же удаление

Comment: Нужно где-то в бд хранить опцию, и при её активности удалять или нет.

Comment: @Alban А как-то без бд можно ?